# How can I use mesos-execute to run a jar

Tags: jar, frameworks, cluster-computing, mesos, marathon

I have set up my mesos cluser correctly with one master and two slaves. What I am trying to do is use the mesos-execute framework to run jar files on the cluster. I can use it to run simple commands like:

```
mesos-execute --master=mesosr:5050 --name="simple-test" --command=echo "hello"
```

Which will run as expected. However if I try to replace that echo "hello" command with something like "java -jar helloWorld.jar" it won't work.

I managed to identify the problem, but I don't know how to fix it. The issue is that the command doesn't run from the home directory, it runs from something similar to this

```
/var/lib/mesos/slaves/3f5439b1-7fab-45d6-876e-7e75b7c15fc9-S0/frameworks/3f5439b1-7fab-45d6-876e-7e75b7c15fc9-0043/executors/java-test/runs/7c20baff-080f-48ee-95fc-3662c388744b
```

I got that path by running "pwd" as a command on mesos-execute.

Now, my question is how do I get out from there? cd doesn't work.
Is there any way for me to get to the home folder or to a special folder where I can put my jars to make them accessible to mesos-execute?

The use case for this application is that there will be a lot of small jar files that will have to be run on the cluster. They don't have to stay alive, so I am not using anything like Marathon for these jars.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From [`mesos-execute -h`](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/src/cli/execute.cpp#L140-L178)

> `--task_group=VALUE`  The value could be a JSON-formatted string of `TaskGroupInfo` or a file path containing the JSON-formatted `TaskGroupInfo`. Path must be of the form `file:///path/to/file` or `/path/to/file`. [See the `TaskGroupInfo` message in `mesos.proto` for the expected format](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/include/mesos/mesos.proto#L1601-L1613). **NOTE:** `agent_id` need not to be set.

Example:

```
{
    "tasks":
       [
          {
           "name": "Name of the task",
           "task_id": {"value" : "Id of the task"},
           "agent_id": {"value" : ""},
           "resources": [{
              "name": "cpus",
              "type": "SCALAR",
              "scalar": {
                  "value": 0.1
               }
             },
             {
              "name": "mem",
              "type": "SCALAR",
              "scalar": {
                  "value": 32
               }
            }],
           "command": {
              "value": "sleep 1000"
             }
         }
       ]
}
```

What interest you most is `command` part. There you can define your task with all files it need to download to run correctly. All possible configuration options for command are specified in [CommandInfo](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/1.2.0/include/mesos/mesos.proto#L570-L636).

Comment: The resource role field should be removed from the example (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-7805)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I figured out how to do it.

I was going about it all wrong, perhaps not the best idea to tackle a new thing at the end of a workday.

What I was trying to do was change directory to the home directory as part of the mesos-execute command. This is not allowed. The way to run a jar that is located in the home directory is to specify the path of the jar in the java -jar command. So the final command, that works, looks like this:

```
mesos-execute --master=mesosr:5050 --name="simple-test" --command="java -jar /home/user/jarFile.jar"
```

This works, and the jar is executed on the cluster.